# Checking the values of public variables in Excel VBA - Locals Window Alternative

Tags: debugging, excel, global-variables, variable-assignment, vba

I have been using the Locals window to check the assignments for procedure level variables.

I have recently updated my code to create a set of public-level variables that read certain inputs from the sheets which do not change from project to project.

When seeking to check these variables, I do not see them in the Locals window, no doubt because they are not locally-defined variables!

Is there an alternative to the Locals Window for Public variables? And if not, how am I supposed to check public variable assignments?

Comment: Hi, can you share some of the code? I tried to do what you say, but I can still see the public variable in the Locals Window (http://postimage.org/image/9dor72s0v/)

Comment: Let me see if I can provide some example code this week.

Comment: Hi Paul.  I realise that this was a few weeks ago, but I am not coding that often!  Anyway, I think that your use of Dim declares mytext at the procedure or module level, rather than the global level.  In my code I am using Public to declare my global variables.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In addition to the Immediate window (as described in the other answer), the Watch window is very helpful in those circumstances. You can activate it in the *View* menu -> *Watch window*:
[image]

Here you can define:

- Any variable (e.g. your public variables)
- A full term, e.g. `ActiveWorkbook.UsedRange.Address`
- The scope of each watch
- Even a breakpoint when the value changes or results in `True` - this is quite handy when debugging, as it allows you quick conditional breakpoints without adding additional code, e.g. if you set a watch to `myVar=0` and active *Break When Value Is True*, the code will automatically stop the moment the potential bug is "initiated"

You can add all of these options in the "Add watch" dialog, which you either get by right clicking on any variable (or other code) in the code module - or by right clicking in the watch window:

[image]

In addition, you can simply edit any watch items in the list by double clicking.

Very handy tool for debugging, esp. in combination with *Locals* and *Immediate* windows.

Answer (score 12):

Use Immediate Window. Press Ctrl + G in your coding envoirnment to goto Immediate Window.
It allows to get and set the value of your variable when you are in debugging mode.
You need to prefix ? to check the value of variable.
 example

```
 ?variableName   press enter to get the value
 variableName ="test" press enter to set the value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you move your set of "public definitions" to the same module which you run your macro-algoritms from, you will get them in the locals window.

I had all my "public definitions" in one sheet (with nothing else), and quickly stumbled upon the problem that I couldn't find any of the variables listed in the locals window, and the module wasn't accesible from the locals window.

So I moved them to the module sheet which I am using for calling my custom procedures.

That being said, it is probably a good methodology to always define certain things/variables/objects by "dim" as to prevent mix-ups, but this hasn't become a problem for me yet, so I rather use the public. - Please give me some warnings if you think this is "reckless", haha.