# Is there a way of doing IF +

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a sheet and what I am doing seems very slow and long winded. I am hoping there is a slicker way of doing it.

I would like to do what in Excel would look like this but in VBA: - `if(Search("5,",A10,1)>0,A5,0)+if(Search("4,",A10,1)>0,A4,0)+if(Search("3,",A10,1)>0,A3,0)` and so on.

The only way I can see to do this in vba, is do the search add the data elsewhere to then do a sum on it later.  I have this: -

```
    Sub AmorTotal_1()

Dim Coll As String
Dim ClTo As String, RuTo As String, ElTo As String, Jig As String, Teth As String, Admin As String, Crane As String
Dim ClToS As Integer, RuToS As Integer, ElToS As Integer, JigS As Integer, TethS As Integer, AdminS As Integer, CraneS As Integer

Coll = "B"
ClTo = 5
RuTo = 6
ElTo = 7
Jig = 8
Teth = 9
Admin = 10
Crane = 11

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Coll & 2).Value

If InStr(1, Range(Coll & 12), "5,") > 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Coll & ClTo).Value
Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 3).Value = 0
End If

If InStr(1, Range(Coll & 12), "6,") > 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Coll & RuTo).Value
Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 4).Value = 0
End If

If InStr(1, Range(Coll & 12), "7,") > 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Coll & ElTo).Value
Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 5).Value = 0
End If

If InStr(1, Range(Coll & 12), "8,") > 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 6).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Coll & Jig).Value
Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 6).Value = 0
End If

If InStr(1, Range(Coll & 12), "9,") > 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 7).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Coll & Teth).Value
Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 7).Value = 0
End If

If InStr(1, Range(Coll & 12), "10,") > 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 8).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Coll & Admin).Value
Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 8).Value = 0
End If

If InStr(1, Range(Coll & 12), "11,") > 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 11).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Coll & Crane).Value
Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 11).Value = 0
End If


ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Coll & 13).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 3).Value + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 4).Value + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 5).Value + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 6).Value + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 7).Value + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 8).Value + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Coll & 9).Value

End Sub
```

I need to do this across 20 columns and multiple rows so was hoping there was a another way.

I have searched the web, and can't find anything or anything I can understand (I am still new to VBA).

Below is an example of some data.  In summary,

The user types in some values of some tools in rows 5-11.  The user may decide that certain tools can be used on other items (items represented by columns), as such they may want to amortise the costs of those tools across the entire those items.  On item one the user has decided rows 8 and 9 (in row 12) can be used across items 1,2,3,5 (row 15). Row 13 takes the value of the prices in cells B8 and B9 in item 1, rows 16 is the amortised value which is the cost of row 2 for each reference item 1,2,3 + 5.  This is done by, this item total cost divided by (total item cost for 1,2,3+5) * amortised value row 13.

Hope this makes sense its a bit tricky to explain.
[image]

Comment: The VBA `IIf()` function is equivalent to Excel's `IF()`, but there's probably a more elegant approach than that. Can you share some sample data and expected outputs?

Comment: What is the range of the full contents of A10?

Comment: Hi @jsheeran I will be able to share the example data on Monday.  I have typed this in manually on my personal laptop as my work computer has lost the ability to connect to the wifi and refuses to hotspot of a phone, which is what i am doing on my personal laptop.  Apologies :(

Comment: @RonRosenfeld good question, so in the example above rows 1 to 9 have costs of tools in them.  The user may choose to amortise these tools with another item (item 1 being column A and so on until Item 20).  In A10 they get to choose which rows they wish to amortise.  So say tool in ranges A4, A5 are also used on item 20, the user would put 4,5, in range A10.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So, in the case you mention, you would want the Sum of A4 and A5?  Would you prefer a formula or VBA?  Which version or Excel.

Comment: This is correct, VBA please and latest version of excel :-) thank you.

Comment: @jsheeran Excel's `IF` function is NOT equivalent to VBA's `IIf` function, because the two expression evaluation engines (Excel's calc engine vs VBA's compiler) are fundamentally different - `IIf` being a function, invoking it from VBA **will evaluate all arguments before passing their result to the function**, whereas Excel's calc engine will "short-circuit" and only evaluate the branches relevant to the calculation. Using `IIf` with anything other than constant expressions makes it side-effecting, and thus easily bug-prone.

Comment: I don't understand at all what you are doing.  "*Row 13 takes the value of the prices in cells 8 and 9 in item 1*"  What are **cells 8 and 9**?  If you mean the values in **rows** 8&9, those values are `60+50 = 110`, not 66. Your logic for row 16 is equally unclear to me.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld hi had auto calculation off and didnt realise.  Image now updated.  Yes 110 is correct.  So Row 16 amortises the value based on the cost.  In the snapshot i just have this simple formula `=SUM($B$13/($B$2+$C$2+$D$2+$F$2))*B2`

Comment: OK, I've changed my response in accord with your more clearly stated specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, here are two functions you can use in B13 and B16

**Note:**

- Since the various cost items are not referred to directly in the formula, the formula will not update automatically if they are changed.
- The formula will update if the list of rows or list of Items cells are changed
- Two workarounds:

  1. Add `Application.Volatile` after the declaration statements of each function (this may slow down the worksheet calculations).
  2. Change the column/row number arguments to range references

```
Option Explicit

'sRows is the cell (or string) containing the commas separated row numbers
'lItemCol is the column number on which to run this calculation.
'    If omitted, it will default to the column containing the formula

Function toolCostToAmortize(sRows As String, Optional lItemCol As Long = 0) As Currency
    Dim v
    Dim P As Currency

If lItemCol = 0 Then lItemCol = Application.Caller.Column

For Each v In Split(sRows, ",")
    P = P + Cells(v, lItemCol)
Next v

toolCostToAmortize = P
End Function
'======================================
'sItemIDX is the cell containing the comma-separated string to use
'cCostToAmortize is the cell reference containing the toolCostToAmortize result
'lItemRow is optional and is the row containing the list of Items (row 1 in your screenshot)
'    If omitted, it will default to row 1

Function amortizedValue(sItemIDX As String, cCostToAmortize As Currency, Optional lItemRow As Long = 1) As Currency
    Dim v
    Dim P As Currency

For Each v In Split(sItemIDX, ",")
    'Assuming Item List starts in column B
    ' But could use other methods to locate table
    P = P + Cells(lItemRow + 1, v + 1)
Next v

amortizedValue = cCostToAmortize / P * Cells(lItemRow + 1, Application.Caller.Column)

End Function
```

They provide the answers shown in your screenshot.

Comment: Hi Ron, i get an error when i run this, i have simply copied and pasted this into sheet 1 vba.  The error is `run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error` any ideas, thank you again for your help. :-)

Comment: Hi Ron, could i be cheeky and request that you put a few more notes on it please, so i can learn what it is doing please? As i am new there are parts i don't understand.  Thank you.

Comment: @StevenByrne I've added some comments explaining the function arguments. Possibly you don't have them set up correctly. Using your data, I do not see that error. I've also added a note about possible issues.  Suggest you examine HELP for the various VBA functions used, and examine the variables in the `Locals` window, stepping through the UDF step-by-step as it runs.  Then ask if you have a specific question.

Comment: @StevenByrne *i have simply copied and pasted this into **sheet 1 vba.***  It needs to be in a **Regular Module**, not behind a sheet.

Comment: Hi Ron, thank you for your help.  I have now got `toolCostToAmortize` to work but can't get the other to work.  Thanks for your help on this.  Apologies, i am very, very new to this.  So my first mistake on this was, i put it in the wrong place, second i had no idea a function created a new formula in a cell.  Also i have no idea how to examine the variables in the `Locals` window.   Really appreciate the guidance : ) So to get the last bit to work which is obviously me doing something wrong, i have put the `=amortizedValue(B15)` in cell `B16` is this correct?

Comment: @StevenByrne Just like the built-in functions, you need to provide arguments for **each** of the non-optional function arguments, not just some of them as you are doing. For hints on examining the Locals window, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031323/checking-the-values-of-public-variables-in-excel-vba-locals-window-alternative). Also, do an internet search for more information.

Comment: Hi Ron, i am still stuck on the second part `amortizedValue`.  How does it know what cells to look at and how would this work if the formula is done on say column D?  Do i have to name a range for a row? Apologies for all the questions.

Comment: Hi Ron, now sussed it thank you very much! That is amazing! :)