# If Function based on Split

Tags: excel, vba

I have 20 columns of data that has an amortisation formula in it.

I need to check if the amortisation meets two criteria.

Based on a `split` of row 15 I need it to check that both items (item refers to row 1) say they are include (row 3) and that both items have the same value (row 13).

Now the split could be item 1,2,4, or 1,2 or 1,5 etc. any combination based on the user inputs.

If they are not included state "Check" if they are state "" in row 18.

I know how to do an if function, but not based on a split.

I know how to do the split as part of a function through guidance I received here but I cant work out how to add an IF into a function.

My functions are used in rows 13 and 16 [Function Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541716/is-there-a-way-of-doing-if/61542177?noredirect=1#comment109021352_61542177)

[image]

My attempt:

```vb
Function checkIf(sItemIDX As String, cCostToAmortize As Currency, Optional lItemRow As Long = 1) As String
Dim v
Dim P As Currency
Application.Volatile
For Each v In Split(sItemIDX, ",")
    'Assuming Item List starts in column B
    ' But could use other methods to locate table
    P = P + Cells(lItemRow + 1, v + 1)
Next v

checkIf = IF(cCostToAmortize = Cells(lItemRow + 1, Application.Caller.Column) then IF(cCostToAmortize = Cells(lItemRow + 1, Application.Caller.Column) Then "" Else "Check"
End If

End Function
```

How I would like the outcome to look (the colours are there to make it easier to explain).
[image]

In row 18 I want to do a check, in my head this would be done in the following steps.

1. Split row 15, each number within row 15 represents the item (row 1).
   In the final sheet there could be 20 numbers in any cell in row 15.
2. Based on those numbers a If statement will be completed to check the included choice (row 3) all should be yes if entered into row
   15, example B15 says item 1 and 2 so both Item 1 (b) and Item 2 (c)
   on row 3 should say yes.  As this is not the case it should return
   "Check" in row 18 column B and C.
3. Next stage if these were both yes as is the case on items 4 (e) and items 5 (f) then it checks to make sure both the tool cost to
   amortise is the same value row 13.  In this example they are not
   (highlighted in red) so again it puts "Check" in row 18 column E and
   F.

If it doesnt have anything in row 15 then it is fine so it would be "", and using columns B and C again if they both said yes in row 3 then that would return a "" to.

Note in the final version Row 15 could contain 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 in each cell on row 15 which would mean they would all need to be compared.

Image to check.
[image]

Formula image
[image]

Comment: Please share your code as debugging existing code is exactly what this site is for. No need for us to start from scratch when you may be closer than you think.

Comment: Apologies @urdearboy i thought this may confuse people.  Now added.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you really need reading your question and also looking at the code. In order to understand something from your function, we must know how the function is called. What the string `sItemIDX` is, in fact? Would it be all the row in discussion joined using a separator? If not what it is? What `lItemRow` is? According to its name we can guess it would be the processed row number. But it becomes more difficult for somebody not interested in such a code to firstly make the puzzle.And your function Ends at the 5th row...

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, this is why I left the code out initially.  The code is probably nonsense as I am still learning.  I have taken the code from another question I have asked which is linked and tried adding an ‘if’ into it.  sItemIDX is row 12, 1ItemRow is row 15.  These are defined by calling the function in the sheet and selecting the cell followed by a common.

Comment: Hi @sjr yes it’s a pasting error. I will amend thank you.

Comment: It might help if you posted a screenshot showing expected results based on your data as it's not clear to me.

Comment: Hi @SJR thank you for the suggestion, i have updated with more detail and a screen shot as advised.  Please let me know if it needs further information.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that helps (though don't know if row 16 features at all). Perhaps you want to have a go yourself? So you'd use Split on row 15, loop through the resulting array. As soon as you find a No in row 3 stop. As soon as an entry in row 13 is different to the last one stop. If you haven't stopped by the time you get to the last item you know it's "passed". That is in outline how I'd approach it. You can shorten a code a little because if you find a string in row 15 you've already encountered you can just copy the previous result.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance @SJR, i will go away and look up loops. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, and you have Excel for windows 2013+, you can do this with worksheet functions.

For example, to Split the comma separated data into separate array elements, you can use:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B15,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s")
```

*(substitute B12 for B15 where appropriate)*

So, your formulas could be as follows:

```
B13:  =IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(B$1:B$11,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B12,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"))),0)

B14:  =SUM(B5:B11,-B13)

B16: =IFERROR(B13/SUM(INDEX($B$2:$U$2,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B15,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s")))*B2,0)

B17:  =B14+B16

B18:
=IFERROR(
        IF(AND(
                     AND(INDEX($B$3:$U$3,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B15,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"))="Yes"),
                     AND(INDEX($B$13:$U$13,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B15,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"))=B13)),
             "","Check"),
"")
```

In the screenshot below, "Check" appears because of the `No` on the `Item 2 Included` row.

If you change `C3` to `Yes`, the `check` in row 18 will disappear.

The formulas will handle 20 columns of data.  If you have more (or fewer), change the references to `Bn:Un` in the various formulas accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214101/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-rosenfeld-if-function-based-on-split).