# VBA Splitting Merged Documents; works in Windows but not in MacOS?

Tags: vba, windows, macos, ms-word

Thank you in advance for anyone reading this and able to help :)

I've adapted a macro for splitting a merged document in Word. It works great on Windows and performs as expected. However, on MacOS, it crashes and pops up with "Run-time error 4198: Command Failed." Part of the difficulty is that I don't actually even use a Mac; I sent the macro to a colleague to test and that's when I got the error. This had made troubleshooting even more difficult... Whenever that colleague clicked 'Debug' the error centered around the following line. Full code below:

`.SaveAs FileName:=StrTxt & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False`

Full code:

````
' Edited from: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, StrTxt As String
Dim rng As Range, Doc As Document, HdFt As HeaderFooter

Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"

j = InputBox("How many Section breaks are there per record?", "Split By Sections", 1)

With ActiveDocument
' Process each Section
For i = 1 To .Sections.Count - 1 Step j
With .Sections(i)

'*****
' Get the 1st paragraph
Set rng = .Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
With rng
' Contract the range to exclude the final paragraph break
.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
StrTxt = .Text
For k = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
StrTxt = Replace(StrTxt, Mid(StrNoChr, k, 1), "_")
Next
End With

' Construct the destination file path & name
StrTxt = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & StrTxt
'*****
' Get the whole Section
Set rng = .Range
With rng
If j > 1 Then .MoveEnd wdSection, j - 1
'Contract the range to exclude the Section break
.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
' Copy the range
.Copy
End With
End With

' Create the output document
Set Doc = Documents.Add(Template:=ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName, Visible:=False)

With Doc
' Paste contents into the output document, preserving the formatting
.Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
' Delete trailing paragraph breaks & page breaks at the end
While .Characters.Last.Previous = vbCr Or .Characters.Last.Previous = Chr(12)
.Characters.Last.Previous = vbNullString
Wend

' Replicate the headers & footers
For Each HdFt In rng.Sections(j).Headers
.Sections(j).Headers(HdFt.Index).Range.FormattedText = HdFt.Range.FormattedText
Next

For Each HdFt In rng.Sections(j).Footers
.Sections(j).Footers(HdFt.Index).Range.FormattedText = HdFt.Range.FormattedText
Next

' Save & close the output document

.SaveAs FileName:=StrTxt & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False

' and/or:

' .SaveAs FileName:=StrTxt & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With

Next

End With

Set rng = Nothing: Set Doc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub```
````

Comment: find out what value `StrTxt` contains when that line tried to execute. I'm guessing there is some issue with the file name/path for saving on mac?

Comment: Hi @ArcherBird, do you have a recommendation for how to do that? Sorry, I'm less than familiar with VBA. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `StrTxt = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & StrTxt` -> is the backslash the path separator on Mac?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15032261/6071871) shows a good way of using the watch window to look at variables during runtime. If you have a guy running this elsewhere on a mac, you could add a line of code just before your problematic line to print the value in a text box and have your guy send that to you: `inputbox "Copy the below text", "Copy Text", StrTxt`

Comment: @BigBen In Word 2016/365/2019 it would be "/" on the Mac filesystem. In Mac Word 2011 it would be ":". You can use Application.PathSeparator to give you the correct character on Windows Word, Mac Word 2011 nd later, bearing in mind that "\" and ":" are not the right separator characters if the file is beign saved to HTML etc.

Comment: @slightlysnarky has it: use ```Application.PathSeparator``` to replace the backslash. If you still have issues, please tell us which line of code raises the error.